# doubleclick DFP refresh adunit dynamically in HTML5 Mobile web app

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, mobile, google-dfp

I am building an HTML5 mobile web application.

It loads, initializes and builds the interface.
The user can then use it to pull in content through feeds. So the content the user is viewing changes and is displayed in the existing interface.

I am serving ads through DFP - DoubleClick For Publishers... a process that I am certainly new to.

In the head, I run the init code:

```
var ad1;

// THIS IS THE STRING THAT NEEDS TO CHANGE TO REFLECT DIFFERENT CONTENT ***
var adunit = '/8013/digital.first.media.test.site/Mobile/News';     

googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    ad1 = googletag.defineSlot( adunit, [[300, 50], [320, 50]],  'story_ad_top').setTargeting('pos',['mobile_section_top']).addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
    googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();        //turns off rendering on initial load
    googletag.enableServices();
});
```

I can then refresh the ad anytime I want by calling:

```
googletag.pubads().refresh([ad1]);
```

This works fine... except the user is viewing different content, so the adunit string set on init is no longer up-to-date. I need to update that string... but I can not find a way to do that.

I have a JSFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wqMXV/3/

The example has 3 buttons that reflect the user viewing different content.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined the adunit you cannot change it as far as I am aware.

What you could do is setup the line items that are showing in that ad unit to be targeted with a custom targeting string, then you could use the clearTargeting and setTargeting methods [described here](http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1650154&expand=adslot_details#addService) to set a new custom targeting string before firing your refresh command.

That should allow you to change the ad based on where the user is in the app.